# ¿Cuando se usa esta expresión PHP? ( $var = true ? true : false; )

Tags: php

Tengo duda desde hace un tiempo con relación a esta expresión (o lo que pudiera ser similar). La uso en construcciones como esta:

```
$variable = isset($_POST['valor']) ? $_POST['valor'] : NULL;
```

La he usado porque la he visto en algunos scripts o ejemplos que me han sido útiles para construir mis propias expresiones, pero no tengo la certeza de cuando debe usarse o por qué. Traté de indagar buscando (si busqué) pero supongo que simplemente no supe como realizar la búsqueda adecuadamente y no había tenido éxito (ni en el manual de PHP pude encontrar algo claro).

Entiendo (o hago suposición) que al declarar la variable de esta manera se esta diciendo que, si existe "$_POST['valor']" entonces se asigne el valor dependiendo de si es falso o verdadero, es decir, que si es verdadero devuelve el valor de la variable post que se indica, de lo contrario (si es falso) se queda vacío. Esto me parece como una abreviación equivalente a:

```
if (isset($_POST['valor'])) {
  $variable = $_POST['valor'];
} else {
  $variable = NULL;
}
```

Si es el caso, hay alguna situación donde deba o sea más recomendable usarse? o es sólo una opción para escribir menos código?

No me gusta usar o hacer cosas sólo por inercia y sin saber exactamente su función y su razón de ser. Prefiero salir de esta duda, así que, alguien que me de su retroalimentación?

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apoyo tu forma de aprender, entendiendo cada una de las cosas que haces o usas.

Te cuento que es exactamente lo que crees, esa es una forma abreviada del condicional IF, haciendo uso del operador ternario (?:) y se usa para validaciones cortas. Si buscas como "operador ternario" o "if en una linea" podrás encontrar más información. Es importante aclarar que este operador existe en muchos lenguajes de programación, asi que puedes usarlo en todos ellos.

Comment: Oh, "operador ternario"!! Excelente, con el término correcto es más fácil encontrar la solución, jeje. Muchas gracias man, es justo la respuesta que buscaba. Saludos!

Comment: Con gusto, Saludos!

Comment: Solo como comentario, quizás no siempre sea igual. Indagando un poco [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else/3565374) menciona que va a depender del compilador, sin embargo, hoy en día en los compiladores moderno no existe diferencia significativa.

Comment: @VictorRoque Gracias por el aporte, por eso quería saber si hay alguna razón para preferir usarlo o no usarlo, así que también lo tendré en cuenta. Saludos.